# dot vs. slash in XPath expression

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I came across an unusual problem. I have this XML:

```
<T durationMs="400">
  <foo durationMs="407">
    <foo-child durationMs="307" />
  </foo>
  <bar durationMs="208">
    <bar-child durationMs="108" />
  </bar>
</T>
```

I am using XPathExtentions to get an XElement out of this XML:

```
var xe = XElement.Parse(s);
var foo = xe.XPathSelectElement("/T/foo")
```

It returns nothing. However if I use:

```
var foo = xe.XPathSelectElement("./foo")
```

It gets an elements. So what's the difference between dot and slash in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` selects from the `root` node.

So with `/T/foo` it's trying to match `T->T->foo` which for sure won't match

`.` depicts the current node in which case it would be the root node

`/foo` would work

Comment: I see! XDocument would be something to use a root for, right?

Comment: @Schultz9999 have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256471.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`.` selects the current node.

`/` Selects from the root node.

`//` Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are.

[XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) gives you a brief idea of how selections are done

---

In your case `./foo` denotes selection from root node i.e. `T`